# Sending Multipart/mixed request with boundaries

Tags: rest, api, spring-boot, post, resttemplate

I am trying to create a multipart-mixed request with two sections:

- application/x-url-form-encoded
- multipart/form-data

Example Request:

```
POST http://sample:8080/api/documents HTTP/1.1
Accept: application/json
Accept-Language: en
API-Version: 2
Content-Type: multipart/mixed; boundary=19D523FB
Host: srv2012r2:8080
Content-Length: 11979
Expect: 100-continue

--19D523FB
Content-Type: multipart/form-data

{"fields":[{"Key":"e9e269b9-867f-4cf6-946f-db49091cd52d","Value":"Simplest document ever.docx"}],"storageappid":"d9ca0630-e4f8-4112-a411-ff04d89f2225"}

--19D523FB
Content-Type: multipart/x-www-form-urlencoded
Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="Simplest+document+ever.docx"

--19D523FB--
```

Not able to create the request using RestTemplate in Springboot.